# Can the army of the dead embark on ships?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones*, the dead men don't have ships yet, perhaps building them is too difficult.

Even if they don't know how to sail, we know the White Walkers and King have the ability to think (even if they may have low IQ). Could they just board a ship and ride to all the other islands/lands?

Comment: [Yes an Army of the Dead can definitely embark on ships](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/8a/e6/9e/8ae69ebd3d0c9254a0bcf8cdc63df9b1.gif)

Comment: If they don't know how to sail, what exactly are they supposed to do after boarding a ship? Hope it takes them where they want to go?

Comment: Voted to close as Primarily Opinion Based because as of now no information is given. If information shows up we can re-open the question.

Answer (score 2):

[A purely speculative answer]

The Dead don't know whom to fight and when to fight, till the Night Walkers give the order/instruction. **But, they do know how to fight**. Probably because they were warriors and wild folk.

So, if the Night King or the White Walkers can give them Captain's orders on where to go and how to go, probably a team of dead sea-men can embark on ships.

So, the Night King needs a team of dead sailors for embarking on ships.

Comment: In a separate question someone had speculated that White Walkers don't reanimate the dead but warg into the dead--controlling them directly. In that case only the White Walkers would need to know how to sail.

Comment: The 'White Walkers can Warg into the Dead' is a very interesting theory. I like the idea, but can't help but to think that if the WW's had more finesse/control over their undead army - they would actually be utilizing weapons / swords / arrows to their advantage.... instead of madly clawing.